# Can I publish research in a peer-reviewed journal if parts of it have previously been published in a self published book?

Tags: research-process

The book was not published in English, and I am using a different perspective in the paper, but the same qualitative data.

Comment: Some journals may say no. If you decide to do so - the existence of prior published product should be clearly stated in the cover letter and the book should be referenced by the article.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find any formal policies addressing this specific case, but my intuition is that it would probably be all right.  It could be analogous to publishing sections of a thesis, which is generally accepted.

If you have a journal in mind for the paper, you could contact the editors and ask their position on the issue.  If and when you eventually submit the paper, you should include a note to the editor explaining the situation, and probably mention this in the text of the paper as well.  If you disclose everything, there won't be any ethical issue; the editor can make the decision, and I expect there would be some good journals that won't have a problem with it.

Factors that might be relevant:

- Was the book offered for sale publicly, or distributed privately among colleagues?
- How many copies were produced/sold?
- Did you retain the copyright on the book?